# TK GUI looks different on different linux machines but with same version

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a Tk UI which when executed on different linux machine comes up with different UI. I checked tcl version is 8.6 for both platforms.
The UI looks like this.
invoke method : tclsh script name.tcl

[image]

[image]

I wanted to use 1st one as its more graphical and fonts are readable.
Can you point me to check what is the difference in the tcl version installed on machine B. I assume Tk package could be different, but i dont know how to check.

Answer (score 0):

I think tk still uses good ol'resource databases for X11, which may be different on each platform. Check xrdb(1) for this. Also read ttk::intro(n) and ttk::style(n) to read about ttk widget styles.

System wide defaults go to

```
/usr/lib/X11/app-defaults/∗   Client resource specifications.
```

or similar (check `/etc/X11` and `/usr/share`).

In your home directory there may be `.Xdefaults` for user specific defaults.

But the fonts are selected through fontconfig, which has other default directories. Check `/etc/fonts`.

Comment: I wonder why it's picking a different theme by default. One is `clam` and the other is probably `alt` or `classic`…

Comment: Which file in installation directory is having default theme info ?

Comment: I have downloaded some custom themes from this page
http://wiki.tcl.tk/24094
Can you please tell me how to use it in my tcl code, its located in a directory tcl-tiles.